# Mapping custom domain to the openshift wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, openshift, cname

I have an openshift wordpress blog running at http://blog-example.rhcloud.com/ and  added CNAME records in my DNS management as follows.

```
example.com
www.example.com
```

and works fine. When i type, this leads to my blog home page.But the pages and links in the blog actually leads to openshift naming space. i.e., blog-example.rhcloud.com/?page_id=7

I just want to mask blog-example.rhcloud.com/ to example.com every where in my app.I would be happy to provide further information if any thing required to analyse the issue.

PS: I bought the domain from Big Rock and using their console for CNAME entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go into your WordPress admin and change the url on the settings or options page to use your custom domain instead of the app-domain.rhcloud.com one.  If you want to change it directly in the database (which i don't recommend) it is in the wp_options table under home and siteurl i believe...  But I DO recommend using the WordPress admin.

Comment: i just changed the wordpress url from General settings of my admin.Found it works fine.Thanks for the response.

Comment: thanks it worked like a charm , but now when I go to login or new registration google warn page unsecure , certificate doesnot matches url , I have not installed any new certificate , but default of openshift that comes on all subdomains

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to 
Settings=>General=> Site Address(URL), 
Settings=>General=> wordpress address(url) 
and update it to your custom domain.

[image]

Comment: What should be the WordPress Address (URL)? http://mycustomdomain.com or http://my-app.rhcloud.com?

Comment: Yes, the wordpress Address would be mycustomdomain.com

Comment: Why `Site Address` and not `Wordpress Address`, can you please explain?