# Why WP_CONTENT_URL is based on option `siteurl` instead of `home`

Tags: php, wordpress, cors

Just wondering why by reading the source code in `default-constants.php`:

```
function wp_plugin_directory_constants() {
    if ( !defined('WP_CONTENT_URL') )
        define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content'); // full url - WP_CONTENT_DIR is defined further up
```

I have an alias of my site and my `home`address is different to my `site_url`address causing CORS problems. 
What is the best method to make it point to `home`?

Comment: Define WP_CONTENT_URL ?

Comment: yes, I would expect it was `get_option('home')`

Comment: No it is (as the code shows) get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content' (note the wp-content)

Comment: why then can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value that's used by default, the WordPress address (`siteurl`), covers both of the most common WordPress configurations.

1. WordPress URL and Site URL are the same
2. WordPress is running in a different folder

If you were to use the Site URL (`home`) instead, anybody wishing to run WordPress in a different folder would have to either manually set the content directory constant or move their wp-content directory.

As you aren't running a standard configuration of WordPress, you'll simply need to override the constant yourself.

`get_option()` isn't going to work inside `wp-config.php` so you'll need to manually enter the URL or use another method of detecting it. You're probably better entering it manually in my view however it's going to depend on context.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://example.com/wp-content' );
```

Comment: I had erroneously supposed that for my alias to work I had to change only Site URL (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37017037/1073786). At the end I aligned both URLs to my alias and I do not have CORS problems anymore. Thank you