# get_option() inside wp-config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, configuration

I'm trying to customize the `wp-config.php` file on a WordPress website, and stumbled upon this (old) [article on digwp.com](https://digwp.com/2009/06/wordpress-configuration-tricks/) that recommends setting Cookie Domains in wp-config, which I tried to check if I could see a performance boost.

The same method is described at https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#additional-defined-constants

```
define( 'COOKIEPATH', preg_replace( '|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option( 'home' ) . '/' ) );
define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', preg_replace( '|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option( 'siteurl' ) . '/' ) );
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . 'wp-admin' );
define( 'PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH', preg_replace( '|https?://[^/]+|i', '', WP_PLUGIN_URL ) );
```

However, the result is the following error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_option() in /Users/jrmy/Sites/secretsoflifeanddeath/local/app/public/wp-config.php on line 30
> ( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function get_option() in /Users/jrmy/Sites/secretsoflifeanddeath/local/app/public/wp-config.php on line 30

I searched for answers and was only able to find a comment by [@Nathan Dawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310929/nathan-dawson) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338366/why-wp-content-url-is-based-on-option-siteurl-instead-of-home) that made mention of this:

> get_option() isn't going to work inside wp-config.php so you'll need to manually enter the URL or use another method of detecting it.

➡️ I'd like to understand why `get_option()` doesn't seem to work inside `wp-config.php`, even though it's recommended by WordPress, and what's the preferred alternative method?

---

**NB**:

- I'm using WordPress 6.0.2
- My `wp-config.php` file also contains the following, above the cookie domain declarations:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://domain.tld' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://domain.tld' );
```

Comment: _"to check if I could see a performance boost"_ - any "performance boost" you'd get from limiting your cookies, would hardly be "visible to the naked eye" to begin with. Plus, what it says there on this side, isn't even true any more - you can not exclude cookies from being send to subdomains, by specifying the cookie domain - subdomains are always included, when the domain gets specified. It would have to be left out completely (the actual `Domain=...` part in the resulting Set-Cookie header) for that to be true.

Comment: It fails because option.php file still not included which has get_option() function. any way , these four constants are already being set in default-constants.php file by WordPress, no need to add them in wp-config.php

Comment: @CBroe Well, I tried specifically because I'm no expert on the topic, and Jeff Star specifically mentioned a possible "significant performance boost" in the article. With that being said, if it doesn't make sense anymore, I won't define them. Thanks!

Comment: The performance boost would mainly come from not having to send an extended amount of cookie data with _every_ request, for stuff like static resources that don't even need any cookie data. Previously, this could be achieved by specifying the cookie domain explicitly - `domain.tld` would mean they are valid for that specific domain only, `.domain.tld` would include subdomains. But as MDN tells us, that is outdated - `domain.tld` already includes subdomains now. So the only scenario where this could make sense, is if your main domain was not a "suffix" of your asset domain. Say you make [...]

Comment: [...] your site accessible via `www.domain.tld` only, and all your images get loaded from `img.domain.tld` - then setting the cookie domain to `www.domain.tld` would make sense. But with the setup that is common these days - having the site accessible via just `domain.tld`, without `www` or any other subdomain - there is nothing to be gained by setting the cookie domain to `domain.tld`; even if the images were loaded from `img.domain.tld`, the cookies would still get send with those requests as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_option is declared in option.php which is loaded by wp-load.php (after some more inner includes). If you open wp-load.php around line 40-60 you will see that Wordpress includes wp-config.php and only after that it goes for wp-load.php that means that when you are inside wp-config.php you cannot use the get_option function.

The error is legit, he is right :D i suggest you to just write it hard code like you did with WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the detailed explanation!
When you can't even rely on the official doc, thank god for StackOverflow ;)